# Font-Face not visually correctly on Windows browser

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

I am using font-face and use the following rule for all my fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamBook';
    src: url('gotham-book.eot');
    src: url('gotham-book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('gotham-book.woff') format('woff'),
         url('gotham-book.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('gotham-book.svg#GothamBook') format('svg');
}
```

This is for compatibility with IE, Mozilla, Chrome, Safari. However, the letter looks good on linux and mac browser but not in windows 7. In windows XP typography is improved.

Does anyone know if I have another option which can make font-face look good in every browser?
What is the problem here? Licensed or the converter fonts?

### **WINDOWS**

[image]

### **LINUX, MacOS**

[image]

Comment: Your question title Font-Face not working on Windows browser doesn't fit appropriate coz the @font-face rule is working but the visually different. Of-course! it's the fault of operating system not of font-face. So better choose font.

Comment: I think this is usually not a problem of the OS but of the font. There are millions of fonts looking good in Windows 7 :) But WHAT exactly do you think doesn't look good? A screenshot would help...

Comment: @C-Link You're rigth. I change the title of my question. I prove with google fonts and the visually is correct in all browser. But I need to use others fonts :(

Comment: @RiaElliger OK, I put screenshots in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Most OS's have autohinting engines built-in that compute hints for fonts that lack it. Windows does not so you need to process your fonts through http://www.freetype.org/ttfautohint/ if they lack hinting (and need to choose an autohinting setting, they are not equal and preferences vary).

That, assuming the license of the font you chose allow modifications.